# How Set list of input format in Avidmeux tinypy scripting

Tags: python

I write a script for the Avidemux app to read a folder and get all video files in that folder then split them into a number of the part base on the file size.

the problem is that the input_ext variable which used in the get_folder_content function for checking the file format in the folder. it only gets one format and I can't set a list of formats to check it from the folder.

the input_ext variable only gets one format but I want to set a bunch of formats to it.

my code is this

```
adm = Avidemux()
gui = Gui()

# file set list of  of input files
# input_ext = 'mp4'
input_ext = 'mkv'

# file extension for output files
output_ext = 'MKV'


def convert_file(input_file, output_folder):
    file_size = get_file_size(input_file)

    number_of_part = math.ceil(file_size/2037760000)#equal to 1990 MB 2037760000
    if number_of_part >1:
        for part in range(0,number_of_part):
            file_name = " ".join(basename(input_file).split('.')[0:-1])
            output_file = output_folder + '/' +file_name+'_part'+str(part+1)+'.mkv'
            adm.loadVideo(input_file)
            len = adm.markerB
            adm.clearSegments()
            adm.addSegment(0, 0, adm.markerB)
            adm.markerA = (part/number_of_part)*len
            adm.markerB = ((part+1)/number_of_part)*(len)
            adm.videoCodec("Copy")
            adm.audioClearTracks()
            adm.setSourceTrackLanguage(0,"und")
            if adm.audioTotalTracksCount() <= 0:
                raise("Cannot add audio track 0, total tracks: " + str(adm.audioTotalTracksCount()))
            adm.audioAddTrack(0)
            adm.audioCodec(0, "copy")
            adm.audioSetDrc(0, 0)
            adm.audioSetShift(0, 0, 0)
            adm.setContainer("MKV", "forceAspectRatio=False", "displayWidth=1280", "displayAspectRatio=2", "addColourInfo=False", "colMatrixCoeff=2", "colRange=0", "colTransfer=2", "colPrimaries=2")
            adm.save(output_file)

def main():
    input_folder = gui.dirSelect("Select the source folder")
    
    # input_folder = 
    files = get_folder_content(input_folder, input_ext)
    if files is None:
        gui.displayError("Error", "Folder doesn't containt any ." + input_ext+ " file")
        return 0

    output_folder = gui.dirSelect("Select the output folder")
    # output_folder = 
    for one_file in files:
            convert_file(one_file, output_folder)
    
    print("Done")

main()
```

I want to use input_ext like this :
input_ext = ['mkv','mp4']

Also, I can't find the lib document for tinypy to read function and find the solution

Comment: It doesn't help a lot, I guess, but I'd do this by scripting ffmpeg...

Comment: thanks, @AKX, I look the FFmpeg for an alternative option